# Proving intuitionistic tautologies in Agda

Tags: logic, lambda-calculus, agda

I am to use Agda to prove some intuitionistic tautologies. One of them is the so called **Weak Peirce's Law**
$$
((((A \rightarrow B) \rightarrow A) \rightarrow A) \rightarrow B) \rightarrow B
$$

I understand that there is an "equivalence" between intuitionistic tautologies and programs and their types, that is if I manage to write a function of this type, it works like a proof of this tautology.

The type of the function is `wp : {A B : Set} ((((A -> B) -> A) -> A) -> B) -> B`.

My question is - how do I even approach this thing? I managed to prove some other laws of intuitionistic logic, but with this one I'm kind of stuck. I imagine that somehow I'd like to get the first `A -> B` function and apply `A` to it, but how can I do that if all I get is the whole function `f` of type `((((A -> B) -> A) -> A) -> B)`? Should I use $\lambda$'s for this?

**Additional question:** What does this Law even mean? There are so many implications that I can't even parse it...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For examples like this, they can often by easily written interactively just looking for the only thing possible to do at each stage. So for instance, you start with:

```
wp e = ?
```

and the only option is to apply `e`, at which point Agda will tell you you need to provide $((A → B) → A) → A$, so you introduce a lambda:

```
wp e = e (λ k -> ?)
```

Now you need to give an `A`, which is the result type of `k`, so you apply `k` and abstract again:

```
wp e = e (λ k -> k (λ x -> ?))
```

Now you need to give a `B`. The only thing that results in a `B` is `e`, so you apply it again. However, now your situation is different, because `x` is in scope. And presumably you don't want to follow the same pattern as you did before, so you can write:

```
wp e = e λ k → k (λ x → e (λ _ -> x))
```

In this case, the process is constrained enough that the auto-solver comes up with this solution.

As for what the type means, Peirce's law is similar to double-negation elimination with the $⊥$ replaced with $B$: $$((A → B) → B) → A$$ Peirce's law follows from the above type, because you can massage an $(A → B) → A$ into an $(A → B) → B$ by duplicating the function argument.

So, your overall type can be read as similar to:

$$¬¬(¬¬A → A)$$

Which fits the theme of double-negated classical (propositional) theorems being intuitionistic theorems.

Comment: OK - I just didn't think of passing lambdas to the "top" function. Now that you showed the solution it does seem quite obvious :D Thanks a lot!

Comment: I also have a followup - how could I approach proving something called "irrefutability" that is `irrefutability : {A : Set} → ¬ ¬ (A ∨ ¬ A)`? Following your answer I could do something like

`irrefutability f = f (λ (left a) -> ? ; (right ¬a) -> ?)`

but having only `f` and `a` or `¬a` I don't know how I can get bottom from that...

Comment: Are you using the interactive programming mode? `f` needs to be applied to an `A ∨ ¬ A`, not a function. So Agda will complain about type mismatches as soon as you try to do the λ expression. If you aren't, I'd recommend trying to get it set up, because immediate computer feedback is extremely helpful for this sort of thing.

Comment: I'm using nextjournal, so it's not really interactive - I will try to set up some interactive environment, then :3